# Laravel : Introducing custom Classes/Libraries

Tags: php, laravel, libraries

I have just started learning Laravel and during the process, I found out that we can introduce our custom classes into Laravel using the following:

1. Create a folder say `app/MyLib`
2. Create my class inside `app/MyLib`, say I created `MyDates`
3. Now modify the `ClassLoader::addDirectories` inside the `app/start/global.php` as follows:

   ```
   ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
       ...
       app_path().'/MyLib'
   ));
   ```
4. Access `MyDates` class, however I want

I then came across this article [Laravel 4 Application Setup: App library, Autoloading, Binding](http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading#comment-1467908235) that uses `composer` to autoload the custom libraries. Now the question is, what's the best way to introduce my custom libraries in Laravel i.e. what's the recommended approad and if there are any differences between these approaches, what are those?

Answer (score 1):

its best practice and the only way you should do it, if you modify your composer.json as follows

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        /* HERE YOUR LIBRARY FOLDER */
        "app/MyLib",
    ]
},
```

**EDIT:**
You should run after the change `composer dump-autoload` to autoload your changes

Comment: you may already see that the classmap in `composer.json` does even have the paths from the `classloader`, its even better to safe them at 1 place where everyone knows about.